# How to get the Context in the Thread or to shorten a process?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, file

I make a Media Player and I want load the mp3 Files in an ArrayList. I make this in a method called get getMP3Files. This takes rather long. So I wanted to put that i another Thread. But I don't get Context and the method in run().

Is there a possibility to shorten that process or to get the Context in there?

Thanks in advance!

getMP3Files:

```
private void getMP3Files(Context context, String directory,ArrayList<MusicListArray> mp3_list){

    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    Uri uri;
    byte[] album_art;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    /*File[] files = Directory.listFiles(new MP3FileNameFilter());
    files = Directory.listFiles();*/

    File folder = new File(directory);
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || file.getName().endsWith(".MP3")) {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(context,uri);
                String artist = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
                String title = file.getName();
                album_art = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
                if(album_art != null){
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(album_art, 0, album_art.length);
                }else{
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }
                if(bitmap == null){
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }
                if (title.indexOf(".") > 0)
                    title = title.substring(0, title.lastIndexOf("."));
                if(artist == null){
                    artist = getString(R.string.unknown_artist);
                }

                mp3_list.add(new MusicListArray(title,artist,file,bitmap));
            }
        }else if(file.isDirectory()){
            getMP3Files(context, file.getPath(), mp3_list);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(mp3_list);

    /*for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        mp3_list.add(new MusicListArray(files[i].getName(),"Test",files[i]));
    }*/
    //return mp3_list;
}
```

I want it like this:

```
public void run() {
            getMP3Files(this, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), list);
            StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item,list);
            // Set the adapter for the list view
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);   //Error
        }
```

Comment: Where is located your method run, in an activity or another class?

Comment: The method run() is internal in an activity? in this case you can use MYActivity.this

Comment: `run()` and `getMP3Files` are in the MainActivity.
@phemt.latd doesn't work. :/
Any idea how to shorten the search for files, so I don't need the Thread?

Comment: I suspect that you have a different problem. Please post your LogCat with the error.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/e0tqASWx

Comment: As the exception said, you cannot edit views of another thread. You can put mp3 search in another thread and run view update in the main thread.

Comment: How do I manage to update the View after I get the Files?
Btw. Do you know how to shorten the search process?

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to update UI in non UI thread. The UI should be updated in UI thread only. Push the UI update calls to UI thread using one of following methods suitable for you:

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
View.post(Runnable)
View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
```

In your case, your can avoid complexity of threads and use `AsyncTask`. Which is specially to do time consuming tasks in background.